# flutter convert color (string) to Color

Tags: string, flutter, colors, widget

I have a set of data that comes from DB something like this

```
{
   ...
    name:"any name"
  , something:{
        color:"red"
     }
}
```

based on this (can't change DB ), How can I display the name in a widget with background color dynamically, *"red"* for example

( take a color string **red** converted to **Color** type )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so thanks to @Tipu Sultan and @Er1.

I tried another solution and it works fine

```
Map<String, dynamic> objFormDB= {
    "name": "any name",
    "something": {"color": "red"}
  };

Map<String, Color> nameToColor = {
  'red'  : Colors.red,
  'blue' : Colors.blue,
}
```

and I tried with Text widget

```
Text( objFormDB.name 
     ,style: TextStyle( color : nameToColor[ objFormDB.somethimg.color] )
   )
```

that's simple :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as far as I know.

But you could do something like this:

```dart
Map<String, Color> nameToColor = {
  'red'  : Colors.red,
  'blue' : Colors.blue,
}
```

and then

```dart
{
   ...
    name:"any name"
  , something:{
        color: nameToColor['red'] ?? Color.green //or any other default color
     }
}
```

Comment: I can't change the object coming from DB, do you mean something like ... 
Text( obj.name ,style: TextStyle( color : nameToColor[ obj.somethimg.color] ) ) 
???

Comment: thanks this one works... Text( obj.name ,style: TextStyle( color : nameToColor[ obj.somethimg.color] ) )

Comment: @Salsabeel You're right, I missed that your example shows the data coming from your db. But you seem to have it figured out. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no such way. But if the value of color is known then we can do something like this

```
 Map<String, dynamic> map = {
    "name": "any name",
    "something": {"color": "red"}
  };

  Color getColor(String color) {
    switch (color) {
        //add more color as your wish
      case "red":
        return Colors.red;
      case "blue":
        return Colors.blue;
      case "yellow":
        return Colors.yellow;
      case "orange":
        return Colors.orange;
      case "green":
        return Colors.green;
      default:
        return Colors.transparent;
    }
  }
```

Use this like

```
Container(color: getColor(map['color']),);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put in `variable` Then you can use it.

Example:

```
const Color Red=Colors.red;

{
   ...
    name:"any name"
  , something:{
        color:Red
     }
}
```